# Ajax data based on a condition

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to add an if/else condition for the data section, so that e.g:

```
if(num ==1){
 "Where" : "'"+when +"' < DATE < '"+until +"'" 
}
else
{
 "Where" : "'"+when +"' < DATE_A < '"+until +"'" 
}
```

but i'm failing to do so. Any help on the proper syntax please?

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "Records?DB=EMP&Table=HISTORY",
   dataType : 'xml',
   data : {
      "Where" : "'"+when +"' < DATE < '"+until +"'" 

  },
```

Comment: Use a variable and pass it to `data: { 'Where': myVar },`

Comment: @Tushar i tried it, didn't work. I created a variable outside the ajax and if/else condition and passed  " ' "+when +"' < DATE < '"+until +" ' " to the variable, and gave the variable to where in data.
did i do it wrong?

Comment: @Tushar dear, i would like to apologize,  your solution was correct, i had a mistake in my code...Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can store conditions in variable and also terminate your line with ; symbol.

```
if(num ==1){
var data = "Where:"+when+"< DATE <"+until;
}
else
{
 var data = "Where:"+when+"< DATE_A <"+until;
}
```

**In Ajax:**

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "Records?DB=EMP&Table=HISTORY",
   dataType : 'xml',
   data : {data},
```

Comment: it didn't work, the variable is not taking "Where" :